# Floreant POS GUI Modification

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, border-layout

I am trying to make a modification to Floreant POS. I am trying to move the categories from left to the top.

I found this line of code in the OrderView class:

```
add(categoryView, java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST);
```

So I tried to move it to the top by changing it to:

```
add(categoryView, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

But no luck. I get the following exception:

```
ERROR - Application                - We are sorry, an error has occured.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 0
    at java.awt.Container.getComponent(Container.java:332)
    at com.floreantpos.ui.views.order.CategoryView.initialize(CategoryView.java:67)
    at com.floreantpos.ui.views.order.OrderView.setVisible(OrderView.java:189)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(CardLayout.java:546)
    at com.floreantpos.ui.views.order.RootView.showView(RootView.java:58)
    at com.floreantpos.ui.views.order.DefaultOrderServiceExtension.createNewTicket(DefaultOrderServiceExtension.java:86)
    at com.floreantpos.ui.views.SwitchboardView.doCreateNewTicket(SwitchboardView.java:659)
    at com.floreantpos.ui.views.SwitchboardView.actionPerformed(SwitchboardView.java:855)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's probably trying to retrieve the component you just moved. What's in `CategoryView.java` line 67?

Comment: @DavidYee Line 67: `CategoryButton categoryButton = (CategoryButton) buttonsPanel.getComponent(0);`